Copy & Paste Issues When Using i3 Window Manager
I recently switched to using i3 Window Manager, and I'm having issues with copy-paste. When I copy text or code from my IDE (PHPStorm) and try to paste it into my browser (e.g., ChatGPT, Gmail), it often pastes previously copied content instead. I have to hit Ctrl+C multiple times for it to work. My keyboard functions fine on Windows, so the issue seems specific to i3 on Ubuntu. My super key is set to the "Windows" key. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
i3 version 4.20.1 (2021-11-03)


The issue occurred because of the following sequence of actions:

selected text in window A.
moved the cursor to window B.
hit Ctrl+C while window B was highlighted.

I didn’t realize that simply hovering over window B caused it to become highlighted, which led to the focus shifting unintentionally.
The solution was to disable this automatic focus behavior by adding the following setting:
focus_follows_mouse no

With focus_follows_mouse no, the focus is no longer automatically shifted to a new window just by hovering over it with the mouse, which resolved the issue.
